Difference between "cord" and "rope"
I wonder what is the difference between cord and rope? I looked it up on the internet but couldn't figure out what the difference is. The only thing I found out was that cord is thinner than rope

You've pretty much answered your own question - one is thicker. It's like the difference between a stream and a river, a twig and a branch, a rock and a pebble. They can be the same material, described in almost exactly the same way, yet one is larger than the other.
When it comes to cord and rope, the thickness makes a difference to the application - 'cords' tend to be on delicate things, rope for heavy-duty uses. But most cords and ropes are made for a purpose - they aren't used for those things because of what they are; they are what they are because they were meant for a purpose.
One main difference in word usage - and this came up in another question recently - is that 'cord' is often used to describe a length of material that you pull to activate something, such as the ripcord on a parachute, or the pull cord on a window blind.

Examples of cord: power cord, vocal cords, bungee cords

@AadirajAnil Yes, and all of those are so-called because they involve multiple strands, wrapped or folded. Remember that a power cord (not to be confused with a power chord, guitar players!) has 2 or 3 strands carrying the the live, neutral and sometimes an earth wire, they are just encased in a single rubber tube. 'Rope' also fits this description of having multiple strands wrapped around for strength.

I would note that "cordage" is a term that covers all forms of rope, cord, etc., regardless of thickness. It's mostly a term used in nautical contexts, referring to all the lines involved in a ship's rigging.

Also "cord" is also used without any extra words to mean "power cord," and "rope" certainly can't be used for these. (The lamp's cord is frayed; I can't charge my phone because I lost the cord; etc.)

Rope is the really thick threads or strings that are weaved together to make one bigger strand. Save a few idioms, it's not really used to describe anything else..
Cord refers to a single strand, but it is much more flexible -- it can be made of many different materials and can be used to describe many different types of things, most of which take a "single-strand shape.". For example:

rip cord -- what you pull to open a parachute vocal
vocal chord -- a homophone with a very similar definition
cord (of wood) - 128 cubic feet of split firewood

Nevertheless, despite its versatility, most cords connect something to power, and the default meaning (without context that says otherwise) is power cord.  Something that connects two things together (rather than connecting them to power) is usually called a cable.
